# Add to home screen banner prompt not coming while fetching web manifest from server and then setting path of that inside index.html

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have created one PWA app, so while setting path of manifest in index.html statically, I am getting prompt for A2HS, But while getting manifest from server and setting the manifest href as server URL, Prompt for A2HS  is not coming, from browser 3 dots I am still able to add PWA application. I initially thought that service worker is being registered first and then manifest href set, but then I did register Service worker after fetching manifest and can see in head element href for the manifest.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: `const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://example.com/data';
Http.open("GET", url);
     Http.send();
     Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
       var response = Http.responseText;
       if(response) {
       }
       let manifestUrl = response['data']['pwa-config'].manifestUrl;
        document.querySelector('#pwa-manifest').setAttribute('href', manifestUrl);
       if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js')
       }
      }`

Comment: no error, in fact i am still able to add to home screen from browser 3 dots as manifest is properly setting in browser, just prompt is not coming in this case.(while fetching manifest url from server and setting it inside index.html)

Comment: 2 Questions. What browser & device? What did you do to clear out previous testing attempts?